# simple python script to scan and connect wifi network

Tags: python, network-programming

I am looking for a very simple python code to scan wifi networks and connect with

I am trying to use wifi scan but I am getting error message invalid syntax. I am newbie to python. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What have you written so far and what exactly does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Python` there is a very useful library [Scapy](http://www.devx.com/security/Article/34741), that comes pre-installed in `Backtrack` but in other *nix distributions you need to install it.
And [this](http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/03/wi-fi-sniffer-in-10-lines-of-python.html) is the code that might get you started.

Comment: hi can i somehow use wifi scan or list to do the same ?

Comment: i get error msg when i use wifi scan i.e. invalidsyntax

Comment: Where, i did not get it. Please post the code to let us analyse what are you upto.